Openxlsx Excel file with hyperlinks not working in Protected View
I'm making excel files that contain hyperlinks in some cells using the openxlsx package.
However, when you download the file from the Shiny app, it opens in Protected view. Trying to click on the link warns you, and then returns an error!
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("excel")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$excel <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "New_excel.xlsx"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      data <- data.frame(
        Column1 = rnorm(10),
        Column2 = rnorm(10)
      )
      
      # Make the first column valid hyperlinks
      
      # This actually overwrites the numbers with the link, this is not a problem
      # at this time
      data$Column1 <- "https://www.google.com/"
      class(data$Column1) <- "hyperlink"
      
      
      write.xlsx(data, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Enabling editing allows you to correctly access the links, so they are not corrupted. However, it would be better for my users to just be able to click the links in the first place.
Can I disable protected view? Or make the links function correctly even in protected view?
Additional note that might not be relevant to this specific example: in my main app, it seems that the links get the following appended to their end when opened in this way: %C2%A0 . From what I gather, this is a non-blocking space that makes the URL invalid.

I believe this is just a safety precaution that Excel implements when downloading files from the internet.

I could understand that, but clicking on a link shows the link, a warning, and says "Clicking yes will enable all the hyperlinks in this file, for this session".
Clicking yes then leads to an error opening hyperlinks. Clicking on another displays the warning again, further error on "yes".
Enabling editing on file actually enables links and then they work as expected.
